# How do I accept all changes from a remote?

Tags: merge, git-pull

I'm doing a pull origin some_branch and can see there are a lot of changes. Eventually I don't mind if their erase all mine.

How can I accept them all instead or using mergetool and merge files one by one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just:

```
    git clone $url
```

Seriously! That's the best way.

You could do all sorts of `git reset` and `git branch` commands to move the refs, but the only purpose would be to keep your commits somewhere in your local repository for future reference. If that's the goal, just keep the whole repository as is, and re-clone the origin.

To accept all changes on just one branch, `foo`:

```
    git checkout foo
    git fetch origin +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo
    git reset refs/remotes/origin/foo
```

`foo` will now point at the same commit as `foo` on `origin`. If you want to blow away the files in your working directory, add `--hard` to `git reset`. If you want to merge first, replace `fetch` with `pull`.

You may have a bunch of dangling commits in your local repo, which git may clean-up someday, but for awhile you can still access them via the reflog.

Comment: There's a huge problem with this: I have lots and lots of *additions* to the working tree. I just want to accept/apply all the changes that have been made in the remote. I don't want to throw away all the state of my current work. So this doesn't work as an answer for me.

Answer (score 6):

Or:

```
git status | grep "both " | cut -f2 | cut -f11 -d" " | xargs git checkout --theirs
git status | grep "both " | cut -f2 | cut -f11 -d" " | xargs git add
```

which forces accepting all conflicting remote files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I used, which seems to be OK. I have a branch called "theirs" which contains the new version of everything in the remote. A version named "ours" is my work based on a long-ago version of theirs, which too many irrelevant changes but many additions (new subdirectories of sites/all) that I want to keep.

```
git checkout ours
git checkout theirs -- *.php *.txt *.config modules themes includes scripts
git commit -m "New version with all new key files from 'theirs'"
```

As long as I got the list of files and directories in the second checkout correct, this should be fine.

If I wanted the history to be based on the "theirs" branch I might want to do this the other way round.

Comment: Randy, You can edit that comment, then indent each line of code by 8 spaces (maybe 4?) to show what you mean better. '--ours' and '--theirs' are valid flags, so you should use different words for illustrative branch names. But yes, specifying paths will allow him to get just those files.